# unary operator in std::transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Can someone help explain how does this line of code work?
I don't understand how the operator worked in transform().
Thanks!

```
typedef std::list<int> L;
L l(5);
typedef L::const_iterator CI;
CI cb = l.begin(), ce = l.end();
typedef L::iterator I;
I b = l.begin();
std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, [] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; });
std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<CI::value_type>(std::cout));
```

Comment: what exactly don't you understand, what operator?

Comment: I meant to ask how "[] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; }" works? In transform(), it is supposed to have an operator. I guess it functions as an operator here.

Comment: @Sarah It's unary *operation*, not unary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list has 5 elements initialized by zeroes:

```
L l(5);
```

You can imagine them like

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Iterator pair cb, --ce sets the following range of elements of the list

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
  ^          ^
  |__________|
  cb        --ce
```

The last element of the list is not included in the list due to decreasing ce: `--ce`.
That is the first iterator points to the first element of the list and the second iterator points to the last element of the list.

Iterator ++b sets the begining of the range

```
    ++b
     |          |          
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
  ^          ^
  |__________|
  cb        --ce
```

The algorithm works the following way. In the first iteration the value pointed to by cb is increased and stored in the element pointed to by iterator ++b

```
    ++b
     |          |          
{ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }
  ^          ^
  |__________|
  cb        --ce
```

then the iterators are moved to the right.

```
       ++b
        |       |          
{ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }
     ^       ^
     |_______|
     cb     --ce
```

Then the operation is repeated: the value in the element pointed to by iterator cb is increased and stored in the element pointed to by iterator ++b and you get

```
       ++b
        |       |          
{ 0, 1, 2, 0, 0 }
     ^       ^
     |_______|
     cb     --ce
```

Then again the iterators are moved to right

```
          ++b
           |    |          
{ 0, 1, 2, 0, 0 }
        ^    ^
        |____|
        cb  --ce
```

and so on.

This can be done more simpler and clear with standard algorithm `std::iota` declared in header `<numeric>`. For example

```
#include <numeric>

//...

std::iota( l.begin(), l.end(), 0 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the two approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> l( 5 );

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::transform( l.begin(), std::prev( l.end() ), std::next( l.begin() ),
                    []( int x ) { return ++x; } );

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    l.assign( 5, 0 );

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::iota( l.begin(), l.end(), 0 );

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4
```

If your compiler supports C++ 2014 then you can also do the same the following way:)

```
l.assign( 5, 0 );

for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

std::generate( l.begin(), l.end(), [value = 0]() mutable { return value++; } );

for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output will be the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

The argument nr. 4 is a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), you can optionally have your own function that transform will call. What this: `[] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; }` does is:

Since its a unary operation, you are allowed to have one parameter, and the lambda above has one. (`transform` allows you also to have a binary operation passing two arguments)
The function `transform` calls the lambda above for each element in the range `cb to --ce`.

`CI::value_type n` is an `int`, so transform calls the function passing an int, and increments it before returning it, storing the result in range starting from `++b`.

For example instead of using a lambda, using a function would also work:

```
int inc(int n)
{
    return ++n;
}
std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, inc);
```

Moreover, for me it would make more sense doing this:

```
std::transform(cb, ce, b, [](CI::value_type n){ return ++n; });
```

Going over each value in the range, incrementing the value.
Here is a [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc409a69ce49888)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, [] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; });
```

says:

1. decrement `ce`, increment `b`
2. For each value starting at `cb` and ending at `ce` (noninclusive!), place an incremented-by-1 value starting at `b`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to draw a picture. This line:

```
std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, [] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; });
```

Can be rewritten to:

```
--ce;
++b;
std::transform(cb, ce, b, [] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; });
```

Where:

```
0 --> 0 --> 0 --> 0 --> 0 --> {null}
↑     ↑                 ↑
cb    b                 ce
```

Each step through the loop sets `*b` to `f(*cb) == *cb + 1`, and increments both iterators. So after one step we're at:

```
0 --> 1 --> 0 --> 0 --> 0 --> {null}
      ↑     ↑           ↑
      cb    b           ce
```

After the second:

```
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 0 --> 0 --> {null}
            ↑     ↑     ↑
            cb    b     ce
```

etc.